# How do I keep track of the number of neighbors that each life has using Numpy in the Game of Life?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to create a Game of Life program using Numpy arrays. What I am struggling with at the moment is how to keep track of the number of neighbors each life has, and how to make changes based off of the rules of the game in some sort of looping structure.
Rules:
a. An individual survives if there are two or three individuals in neighboring squares.
b. An individual dies …
a. From overcrowding … if there is more than three individuals in neighboring squares
b. From loneliness… If there is less than 2 individuals in neighboring squares.
c. An individual is born into each square that has exactly three individuals as neighbors.

My Code:

```
# Import numpy
import numpy as np
startingBoard = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.float)
startingBoard[0, 0] = 1
startingBoard[1:4, 1:4] = 1
print('Original Starting Game Board')
print(startingBoard)
print('\n\n')
generations = 0
cycle = 0
for generations in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    cycle += 1
    generations += 1
    print('Spawning generation cycle', cycle)
    previousBoard = np.copy(startingBoard)
    print('Previous Board')
    print(previousBoard, '\n')
    # startingBoard = np.copy(newBoard)
    print('Starting Board')
    print(startingBoard, '\n')
    print('Next Generation Board')
    # print(newBoard, '\n')
    # print('Number of different cells between next gen and starting (next gen - 1):', --------)
    # print('Number of different cells between next gen and previous (next gen - 2):', --------'\n')
```

Comment: Tip (not an answer to your question): you don't need `generations += 1` because the `for` loop already does this by iterating through the items in the list. Also, you can rewrite the `for` loop as `for generations in range(5):`.

Comment: If I gave you a small (say 25x25) grid with cells filled in, how would you determine the number of neighbors in each cell? Can you think a way to do the same thing in code?

Comment: I just made those changes. Thank you! I'm still very new to python so I appreciate all tips.

Comment: I would go to each filled in cell and count the cells that are filled in... but I am not sure how to code that. I was told that I should use the numpy sum function. Still not sure.

Comment: So break your description into smaller pieces. Start with "go to each filled in cell". How do you do this? Do you really only want to visit filled in cells? Or should you visit every cell?

Comment: One way to transform the grid and ‘evolve’ lives is to use 2D convolution and a bitwise mask.  [Here are the scipy docs for 2D convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html). It’s a fun project!

Comment: It should be each cell, determine the number of neighbors, determine the action that needs to be taken and then change it, but that is kind of my original question. I'm not sure how to do that using numpy.